# refactoring within a shell script

Tags: c++, bash, shell, sed

I have been given assignments to do on sed command. I was just thinking of coding a refactoring tool using the command line. Is there a way to access the variables declared in a c++ program externally from a shell script and change their name,type,global and static declarations,etc? Are their specific commands. I am using gcc and gdb in my system.
Googling it up did not give suitable results.

Comment: That would be a rather non-trivial job and definitely not something approachable with sed.

Comment: Okay. No problem. Can u suggest a way to access the variables in a program. Need not be sed. I know sed does a find and replace. Any other way ?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not really possible to locate variables using simple text search because C++ has complex, context-sensitive syntax + preprocessor. The only option is to utilize fully-functional compiler and dump AST (for example using `clang-check`). Yet it won't be possible to rename those variables easily.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @VTT, if you really want to perform any source-to-source transformations on `C++` code then [Clang's tooling library](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) is definitely worth a look.